# How to corrupt a file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, testing, corruption, xfs

I am going to be testing 'xfs_repair'  on some large file systems ( around 50 TB ) as in the past the memory usage is high. While I could test the program only on file systems which were correct it would be good to test them on a corrupt system.

So what would be the best way to corrupt a file system. Extra credit if the method repeatedly gives the same corruption every time....

To give people an idea of what I mean in 2006 ish

"To successfully check or run repair on a multi-terabyte filesystem, you need:

- a 64bit machine
- a 64bit xfs _ repair/xfs _ check binary
- ~2GB RAM per terabyte of filesystem
- 100-200MB of RAM per million inodes in the filesystem.

xfs_repair will usually use less memory than this, but these numbers give you a ballpark figure for what a large filesystem that is > 80% full can require to repair.

FWIW, last time this came up internally, the 29TB filesystem in question took ~75GB of RAM+swap to repair."

Comment: Interesting question, but can the formating of the quote be improved?

Comment: If so I don't know how to ?

Comment: Try surrounding it with `

Comment: This is an interesting test.  I are you planning on posting the results anywhere?

Comment: Well I will probably post to the xfs mailing list and I could always edit this question with the results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

xfs_db has an option blocktrash which

> Trash randomly selected filesystem metadata blocks.  Trashing occurs  to randomly selected bits in the chosen blocks.  This command is available only in debugging  versions of xfs_db.
>   It is useful for testing `xfs_repair(8)` and `xfs_check(8)`.

For example

`xfs_db -x -c blockget -c "blocktrash -s 512109 -n 1000" /dev/xfstest/testfs`

Answer (score 2):

dd blocks to the device where the filesystem resides. You can script this so it is repeatable. Just a few random blocks at random locations, then move on.

Comment: In a 50TB file system which is mostly empty surely you would have to be quiet lucky to corrupt the system ?

Comment: Well, you just have to use enough random blocks :-). Either way, a "collision" is probably more likely than you think, due to the Birthday Paradox : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_Paradox .

Answer (score 1):

You could try overwriting first 512 bytes (MBR and partition table) of the block device.

Back it up first:

```
dd if=/dev/device bs=512 count=1 of=backup.bin
```

And zero it later:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=1 of=/dev/device
```

Your machine should not boot after that, you can test XFS repair using live CD.

Comment: I want to have a relatively small corruption as run time and memory usage are dependent on the number of files and the size of the filesystem

Comment: This is just 512 bytes of corruption. This just checks whether the filesystem is able to recover without any information on how the filesystem should look like - if xfs hasn't stowed away some spare superblocks somewhere.